# PHP: Put request erroring because of param type passed

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, put, typeof

So, my php is terrible being an FE engineer but need to fix something fairly quick.

I'm hitting an endpoint of an API that stack trace errors to/on this **BE function**:

```
/**
* 
* @param string $token
* @return \stdClass|null
*/
protected function getInstance(string $token)
 {
     $instance = PubSub::getInstance($token);
     return $instance;
 }
```

Here is my **fe code** that is hitting it (angular1):

```
$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: $rootScope.quizURI + '/API/quiz/control/timer',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': $rootScope.teacher_token
    },
    data: {
        'instance_token': $rootScope.teacherInstanceToken
    }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $log.debug('response from control timer put', response);
    });
```

**Workings:**

- Yes, $rootScope.teacher_token is a string.
- Yes, here there's a response error in the browser console:

*Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to API\Controller\Base::getInstance() must be of the type string, null given, called*

Any pointers would make my Easter ;)

**EDIT:**

Blunder on my part. A var was undefined *wa wa waaaaa*

Comment: Isn't what you're sending it the `$rootScope.teacherInstanceToken`? Which is under the `data:` attribute? Not the `$rootScope.teacher_token`, since that's just a header?

Comment: Clearly `$token` is empty when you call it. In your PHP, you receive the data and then pass it on to `getInstance`. Can you include the lines of code that do that? As it stands, we have no idea what the value of `$token` is.

Comment: @Manngo blunder on my part! undefined $rootScope.teacherInstanceToken! You get 10 points!

Comment: @HarryL Happy Easter